# Некорректное отображение на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Пытаюсь с помощью flexbox сделать элементарную адаптацию
в браузере отображается так, как и должно (даже в инспекторе, где можно эмулировать просмотр со смартфона), но на самом телефоне по факту все уезжает.
[Ссылка на CodePen](http://codepen.io/Marates/pen/NyWOag)

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* разместим справа */
  background: #6e9cc3;
}

.header a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.header a:hover {
  background: #5c8db7;
}

.wrapper div {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.body_side {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.side {
  background: green;
  height: auto;
  flex: 20%;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  height: auto;
  flex: 80%;
}

.body>div {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.fourth {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}

@media(max-width: 640px) {
  .header {
    flex-flow: column;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* разместим справа */
    background: #6e9cc3;
  }
  .body_side {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  .body {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  .side {
    order: 1;
  }
  .body>div {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">Главная</a>
  <a href="#">Контакты</a>
  <a href="#">О нас</a>
  <a href="#">Продукты</a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="body_side">
    <div class="side">side </div>

    <div class="body">
      <div>first</div>
      <div>second</div>
      <div>third</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="fourth">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Скрин с iphone5]

Comment: А префиксы пробовали проставить? Предполагаю, что сафари на ios чудит.

Comment: в хроме на ios тоже самое